# Mishnayos Set- Many Commentaries

Tags: product-recommendation, mishna, transactions

Does anyone know if there are any Mishnayos sets which have both the Rash Mishantz and the late commentaries? Basically a normal mishnayos set combined with the mishnayos printed in the gemara sets?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The [Zecher Chanoch](https://hebrewbooks.org/37939) edition might be the most comprehensive.

Comment: @Alex it has the Rash MiShantz? I haven't seen it there.

Comment: @robev Hence not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mishnayos Ateres Shlomo](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/mishnayos-ateres-shlomo-large-16-vol--499684.html) has both the classic commentaries on the Mishnayos as well as the Rash, Rosh, and other commentaries found in the back of the gammarah on zeraim and tahros.